# How to suppress the output of `DBCC SHRINKFILE`?

Tags: t-sql

In order to hide the output of `DBCC SHRINKFILE` I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE #Swallow(DbId int, Fileld int, CurrentSize int, MininumSize int, UsedPages int, EstimatedPages int)
INSERT INTO #Swallow EXEC('DBCC SHRINKFILE(''filename'', 0, TRUNCATEONLY)')
```

but it returns the following error:

> *Cannot perform a shrinkfile operation inside a user transaction. Terminate the transaction and reissue the statement.*

How can this be done?

Comment: `sqlcmd -S .\server_name -E -Q "DBCC SHRINKFILE('filename', 0, TRUNCATEONLY)" >> log.txt`

Comment: Why are you trying to suppress output (asking as context may help us provide alternate solutions)?  Are you running the command from a script / somewhere else?  If so it may be simpler to suppress output there...

Comment: @JohnLBevan: I am writing a script for administrators that should output the amount of recovered hard disc space. The script is to be run manually from *Management Studio* and I shouldn't want to scroll all the way down to read the output that I really need.

Comment: One option would be to return a result set holding the answer; rather than outputting the result to console via `print`; i.e. `select @myMessage` instead of `print @myMessage`

Comment: @JohnLBevan That `DBCC` call does output both a result set (one table) and a text message.

Comment: @lad2025 I should like to do it without having to invoke the script from the console.

Comment: `DBCC SHRINKFILE('filename', 0, TRUNCATEONLY) WITH NO_INFOMSGS`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems there's a `WITH NO_INFOMSGS` option:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE('filename', 0, TRUNCATEONLY) WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

Ref: http://ss64.com/sql/dbcc_shrinkfile.html